# What is the ideal image to use to check connectivity in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-image

I have used **hello-world** Docker image to create a deployment and test the pods running. But that image is meant to terminate after it's run once. Is there a light weight image I can use? Like a lightweight server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nginx container. The apline images of NGINX are very small and lightweight.

https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the distroless base image with an Alpine based image.

It is a security-oriented, lightweight Linux distribution based on musl libc and busybox

A smaller image takes less disk size & less time to upload.

Recommendation is **node:8-alpine**